# How to add a gsheet menu item which when clicked opens a tab in the existing sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I can see how to add a menu item. I am getting lost on the syntax for directing to an existing tab in the current sheet.
How do i do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `activate()` on your sheet object to achieve this outcome.

---

#### Example:

```js
function setActiveTab() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sheetName").activate();
}
```

---

#### Documentation:

- [`getSheetByName()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename)
- [`activate()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#activate())

Comment: Thanks. Tested this and its super slow. Is there a way to have it work as quickly as the UI responds when clicking a hyperlink which references a sheet?

Comment: @SimonTaylor not sure I understand - when testing this on my own sheet it takes less than 0.1s. How long is the execution time on your side?

Comment: Was taking 10 - 20 seconds. This was on my Macbook Pro. On my windows box its 1-2 seconds. Might be an issue with my mac.